# how to update one from two radio group from database in android studio

Tags: android, radio-button

I have a question on radio button. I have two radio groups, first is "tipe" and the other is "status". First both radio groups take the value from database and highlight the radio button value from database. Then I want to update it, for example, if I change the data from "tipe" and then I press the update button, then the value of "tipe" is changed in the database. Unfortunately somehow, the value form "status" is lost, and it goes the other way around, which means I have to click both of them every time I want to update it. What should I do if I want to just update 1 type of radio group, while the other stays the same?

Code Android:

```
 import android.app.ProgressDialog;
 import android.content.DialogInterface;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.support.annotation.IdRes;
 import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.text.TextUtils;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.RadioButton;
 import android.widget.RadioGroup;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 import org.json.JSONArray;
 import org.json.JSONException;
 import org.json.JSONObject;

 import java.util.HashMap;

 public class UpdateData extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private EditText editTextNamaOPD, editTextAlamatOPD, editTextPenanggung, editTextIdentitas, editTextNomor, editTextMerk,
        editTextTipe, editTextModel, editTextOS, editTextProcessor, editTextMemory, editTextSwap, editTextHDD, editTextDimensi,
        editTextDaya;

public String Tipe ="";
public String Status1 = "";

RadioGroup status, tipe1;

public RadioButton aktif, mati, tower, rak;

private Button buttonUpdate;
private Button buttonDelete;

private String id;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.status_item);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    id = intent.getStringExtra(Config.EMP_ID);
    //editTextId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextId);
    editTextNamaOPD = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNamaOPD);
    editTextAlamatOPD = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAlamatOPD);
    editTextPenanggung = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPenanggung);
    editTextIdentitas = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextIdentitas);
    editTextNomor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNomor);
    editTextMerk = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMerk);
    //editTextTipe = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTipe);
    editTextModel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextModel);
    editTextOS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextOS);
    editTextProcessor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextProcessor);
    editTextMemory = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMemory);
    editTextSwap = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSwap);
    editTextHDD = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextHDD);
    editTextDimensi = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDimensi);
    editTextDaya = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDaya);

    status = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.status1);
    tipe1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.tipe);

    aktif = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.aktif);
    mati = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.mati);
    tower = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Tower);
    rak = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Rak);


    buttonUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);
    buttonDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

    buttonUpdate.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(this);

    //editTextId.setText(id);

    getEmployee();
}

private void getEmployee(){
    class GetEmployee extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{
        ProgressDialog loading;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(UpdateData.this,"Fetching...","Wait...",false,false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            showEmployee(s);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            String s = rh.sendGetRequestParam(Config.URL_GET_ALL,"?IDserver="+id);
            return s;
        }
    }
    GetEmployee ge = new GetEmployee();
    ge.execute();
}

public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.Tower:
            if (checked)
                Tipe = "Tower";
            break;
        case R.id.Rak:
            if (checked)
                Tipe = "Rak";
            break;
    }
}

public void onRadioButtonClicked2(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.aktif:
            if (checked)
                Status1 = "Aktif";
            break;
        case R.id.mati:
            if(checked)
                Status1 = "Mati";
            break;
    }

}


private void showEmployee(String json){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
        JSONObject c = result.getJSONObject(0);
        String namaopd = c.getString(Config.TAG_NAMAOPD);
        String alamatopd = c.getString(Config.TAG_ALAMATOPD);
        String penanggung = c.getString(Config.TAG_PENANGGUNG);
        String identitas = c.getString(Config.TAG_IDENTITAS);
        String nomor = c.getString(Config.TAG_NOMOR);
        String merk = c.getString(Config.TAG_MERK);
        String tipe = c.getString(Config.TAG_TIPE);
        String model = c.getString(Config.TAG_MODEL);
        String os = c.getString(Config.TAG_OS);
        String processor = c.getString(Config.TAG_PROCESSOR);
        String memory = c.getString(Config.TAG_MEMORY);
        String swap = c.getString(Config.TAG_SWAP);
        String hdd = c.getString(Config.TAG_HDD);
        String dimensi = c.getString(Config.TAG_DIMENSI);
        String daya = c.getString(Config.TAG_DAYA);
        String status1 = c.getString(Config.TAG_STATUS);

        editTextNamaOPD.setText(namaopd);
        editTextAlamatOPD.setText(alamatopd);
        editTextPenanggung.setText(penanggung);
        editTextIdentitas.setText(identitas);
        editTextNomor.setText(nomor);
        editTextMerk.setText(merk);
        //editTextTipe.setText(tipe);
        editTextModel.setText(model);
        editTextOS.setText(os);
        editTextProcessor.setText(processor);
        editTextMemory.setText(memory);
        editTextSwap.setText(swap);
        editTextHDD.setText(hdd);
        editTextDimensi.setText(dimensi);
        editTextDaya.setText(daya);

        if (status1.equals("Mati")) {
            mati.setChecked(true);
            aktif.setChecked(false);
        } else if (status1.equals("Aktif")) {
            aktif.setChecked(true);
            mati.setChecked(false);
        }

        if (tipe.equals("Tower")) {
            tower.setChecked(true);
            rak.setChecked(false);
        } else if (tipe.equals("Rak")) {
            tower.setChecked(false);
            rak.setChecked(true);
        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private void updateEmployee(){
    final String nama = editTextNamaOPD.getText().toString().trim();
    final String alamat = editTextAlamatOPD.getText().toString().trim();
    final String penanggung = editTextPenanggung.getText().toString().trim();
    final String identitas = editTextIdentitas.getText().toString().trim();
    final String nomor = editTextNomor.getText().toString().trim();
    final String merk = editTextMerk.getText().toString().trim();
    final String tipe = Tipe.toString();
    final String model = editTextModel.getText().toString().trim();
    final String os = editTextOS.getText().toString().trim();
    final String processor = editTextProcessor.getText().toString().trim();
    final String memory = editTextMemory.getText().toString().trim();
    final String swap = editTextSwap.getText().toString().trim();
    final String hdd = editTextHDD.getText().toString().trim();
    final String dimensi = editTextDimensi.getText().toString().trim();
    final String daya = editTextDaya.getText().toString().trim();
    final String status = Status1.toString();

    boolean digitsOnly = TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(nomor);

    if(digitsOnly) {

        if(nomor.length() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Nomor Tidak Boleh Kosong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {

            class UpdateEmployee extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
                ProgressDialog loading;

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    loading = ProgressDialog.show(UpdateData.this, "Updating...", "Wait...", false, false);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                    super.onPostExecute(s);
                    loading.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(UpdateData.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                }

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                    hashMap.put(Config.KEY_EMP_ID, id);
                    hashMap.put(Config.KEY_NAMAOPD, nama);
                    hashMap.put(Config.KEY_ALAMATOPD, alamat);
                    hashMap.put(Config.KEY_PENANGGUNG, penanggung);
                    hashMap.put(Config.KEY_IDENTITAS, identitas);
                    hashMap.put(Config.KEY_NOMOR, nomor);
                    hashMap.put(Config.KEY_MERK, merk);
                    hashMap.put(Config.KEY_TIPE, tipe);
                    hashMap.put(Config.KEY_MODEL, model);
                    hashMap.put(Config.KEY_OS, os);
                    hashMap.put(Config.KEY_PROCESSOR, processor);
                    hashMap.put(Config.KEY_MEMORY, memory);
                    hashMap.put(Config.KEY_SWAP, swap);
                    hashMap.put(Config.KEY_HDD, hdd);
                    hashMap.put(Config.KEY_DIMENSI, dimensi);
                    hashMap.put(Config.KEY_DAYA, daya);
                    hashMap.put(Config.KEY_STATUS, status);

                    RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();

                    String s = rh.sendPostRequest(Config.URL_UPDATE_EMP, hashMap);

                    return s;
                }

            }

            UpdateEmployee ue = new UpdateEmployee();
            ue.execute();
        }
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Nomor Harus Angka", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private void deleteEmployee(){
    class DeleteEmployee extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
        ProgressDialog loading;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(UpdateData.this, "Updating...", "Wait...", false, false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(UpdateData.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            String s = rh.sendGetRequestParam(Config.URL_DELETE_EMP,"?IDserver="+id);
            return s;
        }
    }

    DeleteEmployee de = new DeleteEmployee();
    de.execute();
}

private void confirmDeleteEmployee(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this data?");

    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    deleteEmployee();
                    startActivity(new Intent(UpdateData.this,ReadData.class));
                }
            });

    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                }
            });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == buttonUpdate){
        updateEmployee();
    }

    if(v == buttonDelete){
        confirmDeleteEmployee();
    }
}
}
```

update sql:

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','root');
define('PASS','');
define('DB','account');

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');

$id = $_POST['IDserver'];
$S_Nama= $_POST['NamaOPD'];
$S_Alamat = $_POST['AlamatOPD'];
$S_Penanggung = $_POST['NamaPenanggungJawab'];
$S_Identitas = $_POST['IdentitasPenanggung'];
$S_Nomor = $_POST['NomorPenanggung'];
$S_Merk = $_POST['MerkServer'];
$S_Tipe = $_POST['TipeServer'];
$S_Model = $_POST['Model'];
$S_Os = $_POST['OS'];
$S_Processor = $_POST['Processor'];
$S_Memory = $_POST['Memory'];
$S_Swap = $_POST['Swap'];
$S_HDD = $_POST['HDD'];
$S_Dimensi = $_POST['Dimensi'];
$S_Daya = $_POST['DayaListrik'];
$S_Status = $_POST['Status'];

$sql = "UPDATE daftarserver SET NamaOPD = '$S_Nama', AlamatOPD = '$S_Alamat', NamaPenanggungJawab = '$S_Penanggung', IdentitasPenanggung = '$S_Identitas', NomorPenanggung = '$S_Nomor', MerkServer = '$S_Merk', TipeServer = '$S_Tipe', Model = '$S_Model', OS = '$S_Os', Processor = '$S_Processor', Memory = '$S_Memory', Swap = '$S_Swap', HDD = '$S_HDD', Dimensi = '$S_Dimensi', DayaListrik = '$S_Daya', Status = '$S_Status' WHERE IDserver = $id;";

if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
    echo 'Record Updated Successfully';
}
else{
    echo 'Something went wrong';
}

 mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: can you show full code, what you are updating in database.

Comment: ok, wait a minute

Comment: there, i have edit it